# How do I find the name of metamethod?

Tags: python

Consider the following example:

```
import types

methods = ['foo', 'bar']

def metaMethod(self):
    print "method", "<name>"

class Egg:
    def __init__(self):
        for m in methods:
            self.__dict__[m] = types.MethodType(metaMethod, self)

e = Egg()
e.foo()
e.bar()
```

What should I write instead of `"<name>"`, so output be

```
method foo
method bar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass that parameter somehow, so why not let `metaMethod` return a function that knows what to print, instead of printing it directly? (I'm sure there a more ways to do this, this is just one possibility.)

```
import types

methods = ['foo', 'bar']

def metaMethod(self, m):
    def f(self):
        print "method", m
    return f

class Egg:
    def __init__(self):
        for m in methods:
            self.__dict__[m] = types.MethodType(metaMethod(self, m), self)

e = Egg()
e.foo()
e.bar()
```

Running this script prints

```
method foo
method bar
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to make `metaMethod` a class instead of a function.

```
class metaMethod:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __call__(*args, **kwargs):
        print "method", self.name
```